# let $C(x)$ be the free vector space generated by $X$.Then if $Y$ is a second set, $C(X \cup Y) = C(X) \oplus C(Y)$

Tags: linear-algebra, free-groups, direct-sum

In the [book](http://archive.org/details/springer_10.1007-978-1-4%E2%80%A6) of *linear algebra* by Werner Greub, at page $63$, it is asked that,

> Let $X$ be any set and let $C(X)= \{f \mid f: X \to \Gamma$  such that $f(x) \not = 0$ for finitely many $x\in X$ $ \}$ be the free vector space generated by $X$. Show that if $Y$ is a second set, then $C(X \cup Y) = C(X) \oplus C(Y)$

It is clear that if $X \cap Y = \varnothing$, then the equality holds, but if it is not the case, the sum $C(X) \oplus C(Y)$ cannot be direct, so what am I missing in here ?

Comment: It should be a disjoint union. Otherwise $X=Y=\{*\}$ is a counterexample, as $C(X)\cong k$, $ C(Y)\cong k$ but clearly $k\cong C(X) \cong  C(X \cup Y) \ncong C(X)\oplus C(Y) \cong k\oplus k.$

Comment: @Nephry So the question has missing information.

Comment: I'm pretty sure they're just assuming disjointness implicitly by saying "if $Y$ is a second set" instead of "if $Y$ is a set such that $Y\cap X = \varnothing$"

Comment: @Nephry Oh, I see, thanks for pointing out.By the way, just to show that the question is answer, if you post your comment as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as mentioned in the comments, the original problem seems to be phrased a bit imprecisely. "If $Y$ is a second set" should be changed to "If $Y$ is a set, such that $X\cap Y = \varnothing$". Otherwise consider the singleton set(s) $X = Y = \{*\}$. Then $X\cup Y = X$ and we would arrive at
$$k \cong C(X)\cong C(X\cup Y) \cong C(X)\oplus C(Y)\cong k\oplus k,$$
a contradiction.